# Identify numerical root finding algorithm for polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I am currently trying to understand some code and am struggling with the mathematics.

In the code this function is used:

$r(\theta) = \theta +k_0 \theta^3 +k_1 \theta^5 +k_2 \theta^7 +k_3 \theta^9)$

It is also necessary to use the inverse of this function to determine a $\theta_s$ with $r(\theta_s)$ known.
For this the following formula is used:

$ \theta_{n+1}=r_0/(1 +k_0 \theta_n^2 +k_1 \theta_n^4 +k_2 \theta_n^6 +k_3 \theta_n^8)$

With $\theta_0=r(\theta_s)$

In the code $ \theta_{10}$ is calculated and used.

My guess is this is some numerical approach, but every search I did returned nothing relevant.

Can anyone point me to a proof that this converges ?
Alternatively what do I have to look for to understand this ?

Comment: It is a fixed point iteration. Hint: if $\theta_{n+1}=\theta_n$ then $\theta_n$ is a solution of $r(\theta_n)=r_0$.

Comment: Thank you that helped me out a lot.